# <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title> in Karate for swagger api

Tags: selenium, cucumber, karate

I am new to karate framework and trying to retrieve details of employee via api. In swagger api,if I give employee id, it will return employee details like name,designation,gender,salary.How do I achieve it through karate?

This is what I have tried

```
Feature: Check employee details by API

Background: 
* url 'https://api.employeedetails.com/'
* header Authorisation = 'AAbvy'
Scenario: get employee details
  *def users=

"""
{
"Id": 0,
"StartDate": "2020-08-27T09:18:45.547Z",
"EndDate": "2020-08-27T09:18:45.547Z",
"Designation": "string",
"Gender": "string",
"Name": "string",
"Overseas": true,
"TelephoneNumber": "string",

}
"""

Given path '/swagger/ui/MemberAddress/MemberDetails_Get'
And param reference = '1234'
When method GET
Then status 200
Then print response

Output what I am getting : 

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: NewMember.feature:32 - status code was: 404, expected: 
200, response time: 481, url: https://api.employeedetails.com/swagger/ui/Employee/Employee_Get? 
reference=1234, response: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans- 
serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
at ✽.Then status 200 (NewMember.feature:32)
```

Comment: you must be missing something. follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Seems like you are calling the swagger UI endpoint and not your API endpoint. Swagger UI is typically a "helper" for you to play/try out your APIs.

When you click execute on Swagger UI to try out the API you intend to hit you'll see a Curl command showing up below the execute button. Try to use the URL from that command instead, that's the real path of your API, not swagger.